# Using list() to extract a data.table inside of a function

Tags: r, data.table

I must admit that the `data.table` `j` syntax confuses me.

I am attempting to use `list()` to extract a subset of a `data.table` as a `data.table` object as described in [Section 1.4 of the data.table FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf), but I can't get this behavior to work inside of a function.

An example:

```
require(data.table)

## Setup some test data
set.seed(1)
test.data <- data.table( X = rnorm(10),
                         Y = rnorm(10),
                         Z = rnorm(10) )
setkey(test.data, X)

## Notice that I can subset the data table easily with literal names
test.data[, list(X,Y)]
##              X           Y
##  1: -0.8356286 -0.62124058
##  2: -0.8204684 -0.04493361
##  3: -0.6264538  1.51178117
##  4: -0.3053884  0.59390132
##  5:  0.1836433  0.38984324
##  6:  0.3295078  1.12493092
##  7:  0.4874291 -0.01619026
##  8:  0.5757814  0.82122120
##  9:  0.7383247  0.94383621
## 10:  1.5952808 -2.21469989
```

I can even write a function that will return a column of the `data.table` as a vector when passed the name of a column as a character vector:

```
get.a.vector <- function( my.dt, my.column ) {
    ## Step 1: Convert my.column to an expression
    column.exp <- parse(text=my.column)
    ## Step 2: Return the vector
    return( my.dt[, eval(column.exp)] )
}

get.a.vector( test.data, 'X')
 ## [1] -0.8356286 -0.8204684 -0.6264538 -0.3053884  0.1836433  0.3295078
 ## [7]  0.4874291  0.5757814  0.7383247  1.5952808
```

But I cannot pull a similar trick for `list()`. The inline comments are the output from the interactive `browser()` session.

```
get.a.dt <- function( my.dt, my.column ) {
    ## Step 1: Convert my.column to an expression
    column.exp <- parse(text=my.column)

    ## Step 2: Enter the browser to play around
    browser()

    ## Step 3: Verity that a literal X works:
    my.dt[, list(X)]
    ## << not shown >>

    ## Step 4: Attempt to evaluate the parsed experssion
    my.dt[, list( eval(column.exp)]
    ## Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(format(rn, right = TRUE),  (from data.table.example.R@1032mCJ#7) :
    ##   length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

    return( my.dt[, list(eval(column.exp))] )
}

get.a.dt( test.data, "X" )
```

What am I missing?

**Update:**

Due to some confusion as to why I would want to do this I wanted to clarify. My use case is when I need to access a data.table column when when I generate the name. Something like this:

```
set.seed(2)
test.data[, X.1 := rnorm(10)]
which.column <- 'X'
new.column   <- paste(which.column, '.1', sep="")

get.a.dt( test.data, new.column )
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I'm confused - don't you simply want `test.data[, new.column, with = FALSE]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you simply want:

```
dt = data.table(a = 1:5, b = 2:6, c = 3:7)

var = "a"
dt[, var, with = FALSE]
#   a
#1: 1
#2: 2
#3: 3
#4: 4
#5: 5
```

But just for fun, here's a universal retriever function, that you can give either variable names or variables:

```
retrieve = function(dt, ...) {
  vars = as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1])
  dt[, vars, with = FALSE]
}

retrieve(dt, a)
#   a
#1: 1
#2: 2
#3: 3
#4: 4
#5: 5

retrieve(dt, b, "c")
#   b c
#1: 2 3
#2: 3 4
#3: 4 5
#4: 5 6
#5: 6 7
```

Comment: I knew it must have been simple! Thanks. (I completely passed over the with option when reading the documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

`eval` goes to `parent.frame()` environment. If you really want to use this method for getting a column (why?????), use `get`:

```
get.a.dt <- function( my.dt, my.column ) {
    return( my.dt[, list(get(my.column))] )
}

get.a.dt( test.data, "X" )
```

Comment: I was also thinking that, but I got stuck with `get.a.dt( test.data, c("X", "Y") )`

Comment: This doesn't quite work because it drops the name 'X' and replaces it with 'V1': ` get.a.dt( test.data, "X" )
            V1
 1: -0.8356286
 2: -0.8204684`

Comment: I was unaware of the `get` function. Thanks for pointing it out to me. Any ideas why using it loses the name of the column? (And FWIW this is just a minimal example. My application involves subsetting a data.table where some of the columns are known a priori and some are not. Hence the need for `list()` in the `J` argument.)